# .htaccess redirect subdirectory to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all pages under a specific folder to another domain with different sub folders

For example:

FROM: `https://www.my.domain.com/user/myuser/test.png`

TO: `https://www.newdomain.com/all/allegato1.png`

I have try many htaccess file but all not work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.my.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^user/myuser/(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/all/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I insert my .htaccess into the dir `my.domain.com/user/myuser/`

How can i made this rule? Thanks for your help

Comment: The directive you posted (and in the current answer) would redirect `test.png` to `test.png` (the same filename) at the new domain, however, your example suggests this should redirect to `allegato1.png` 
 - an entirely different filename? Can you please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/user/myuser/.htaccess` following rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.newdomain.com/all/$0 [R=301,L]
```